# Is it possible to convert Ext.define to a jQuery equivalent

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I've never worked with Ext.JS and I've been asked to convert some Ext.JS code to jQuery? I can see a class is being made in the code using Ext.js like so:

```
Ext.define("SomeWidgetOrPlugIN", {
    foo:'hello', 
    bar: function(){
        return ' world';
    }
});
```

Needless to say I am simplifyng the example but does this port exactly to the jQuery extend method (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) or do I need to look into another jQuery method?

As far as I can see in all the code I must reconfigure / refactor Ext.define is the only issue that may give me issues, other methods like `Ext.get` & `Ext.query` can easily be ported to jQuery.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use jquery plugin boilerplate which has all the things you need for the new plugin / component.
https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/jquery.boilerplate.js

Comment: Ext.JS is *vastly* different from jQuery. The Ext philosophy is that you create *everything* via JavaScript and its internal tools; it's more like writing code for a Swing desktop application than it is like writing a web UI (in some ways).